# Inconsistent kerning in units when using detect-all

Tags: siunitx, kerning

When using the siunitx v3 option `detect-all`, the space between prefix and unit changes when in text mode. See the yellow markings in the image below, where the space between k and V is very small in text mode when `detect-all` is enabled. In the first row, without `detect-all`, the spacing is consistent. (See the table in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682752/12440 for more examples)

Is this behavior intentional or a bug?

[image: Different spacing with detect-all]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\texttt{default}: & text: \qty{5}{\kilo\volt}, math: $\qty{5}{\kilo\volt}$\\
\texttt{detect-all}: & \sisetup{detect-all}text: \qty{5}{\kilo\volt}, math: $\qty{5}{\kilo\volt}$\\
\texttt{sffamily}: & \sisetup{detect-all}\sffamily text: \qty{5}{\kilo\volt}, math: $\qty{5}{\kilo\volt}$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `detect-all` is a v2 option, which I don't have an equivalent name for in v3: looking at the best way to do font control, it turns out that one shouldn't conceptualise as 'detection' at all. So the v3 version of `detect-all` is an approximation to the older option but using the new code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is simply that one is typeset in text mode, the other inside `\mathrm`(or `\mathsf`)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
kV vs $\mathrm{kV}$

\sffamily kV vs $\mathsf{kV}$
\end{document}
```

Note that this only happens when compiling with `lualatex` or `xelatex`, not `pdflatex`. What you see is the difference between Latin Modern and Computer Modern: with Unicode engines, LaTeX chooses Latin Modern for the body font, but `\mathrm` is still Computer Modern.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145321/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-inconsistent-kerning-in-units-when-using-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.